# Activity in a dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

It is possible  to set an activity in a dialog?My dialog is part of the class1 extends activity, it possible to set my dialog with class 2 extends activity? I want that the whole activity 2 run in the dialog

Comment: You can set a layout as the view for activity, but I am not sure its what you want.

AFAIK you can't pass another activity as the layout. 

Will you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: As @DevTest said, your question is unclear. Do you want the Activity2 layout to show in the dialog, do you want to start Activity2 from the dialog, do you want the whole Activity2 to run in the dialog?

Comment: I want the whole activity 2 run in the dialog of activity 1

Comment: It is not possible AFAIK. Why can't you make the Activity "Class 2" as the dialog?

Comment: Because in a dialog there is a possibility to set setcancelable, in this way when I touched outside the view of dialog, the dialog does not close

Comment: setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
Using this would open activity which has style of dialog.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250404/unable-to-interact-with-android-custom-dialog/14250579#14250579 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried defining your `Activity` as `Dialog` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```